# How can I import library at android-studio?

Tags: android, api, reference, module, android-studio

I'm using 'android studio' and I'm so beginner.
But I can't and don't know how to use it.

Ah, I'm using window 8 64bit and Now I want to use "https://github.com/square/android-times-square".

until now I use 'Project structure -> Modules -> + -> Import Module -> android-time-square-master ( unpacked)\library(Unmark test and select 3) -> go to 'Perhaps (It's my Project Name but there also exist PerhapsProject too)' -> go to Dependancy -> + -> Library -> Java -> android-time-square-master.zip (Unmark test) and then apply, Ok '

Then go to my layout.xml fill in the code, fill the Activity they said to me but It doesn't work.

Really Really sorry but Can you told step by step? T.T

I hope to make Activity that show calendars. Help me. Thanks, really really thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio uses Gradle for building. Version 2.2 should pick up all libraries specified in build.gradle file. However, If you change anything in Project Structure dialog it won't update build.gradle file.

Open

```
-project_root
    -module_root
        build.gradle
```

This file should NOT be empty. There is another empty build.gradle in the project_root folder so do not confuse them. Add all libraries you need inside dependencies closure. Do not confuse dependencies closure with buildscript.dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    //here is depenency from Maven Central Repository
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    //here is dependency from your local libs folder
    compile files('libs/mylib.jar')
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should consider about that. Thx!